# Update all zip files

Tags: zip, 7-zip

I have several hundred zip files that I want to add a description file to. I want the descriptions inside the description files to be the name of the files without the extensions.

Example file names:

File_name_one.zip
File_name_two.zip
Filename_three.zip

Example description file: description.txt

End result: I want to add the description file (ex: description.txt) to each of the zip archives, note that the content for each description.txt file will be different for each of the files.

Example result: inside each zip is description.txt

Can someone please help me accomplish this?

I am using ubuntu linux so a bash script would be better for me, but a batch file is also ok, if that is easier for you. I don't mind how you get it, as long as you get it.

Comment: Hi Brian, I am glad you are using the forum but SuperUser isn't a script writing service. ***if that is easier for you. I don't mind how you get it, as long as you get it*** No, that's not how it works here.  Try to solve the problem yourself and people here will help you if you get stuck.  What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :

```
❯ ls
test.zip
❯ unzip -l test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2021-10-29 15:35   test/
      186  2021-10-29 15:35   test/HTML File.html
     3021  2021-10-29 15:35   test/Illustration Document.odg
     5089  2021-10-29 15:35   test/Presentation Document.odp
     5089  2021-10-29 15:35   test/Presentation Document (1).odp
     6301  2021-10-29 15:35   test/Spread Sheet Document.ods
     4263  2021-10-29 15:35   test/Text Document.odt
---------                     -------
    23949                     7 files
❯ mkdir test
❯ echo "add your description" > test/desc.txt
❯ zip -ur test.zip test
updating: test/ (stored 0%)
  adding: test/desc.txt (stored 0%)
❯ unzip -l test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2021-10-29 15:37   test/
      186  2021-10-29 15:35   test/HTML File.html
     3021  2021-10-29 15:35   test/Illustration Document.odg
     5089  2021-10-29 15:35   test/Presentation Document.odp
     5089  2021-10-29 15:35   test/Presentation Document (1).odp
     6301  2021-10-29 15:35   test/Spread Sheet Document.ods
     4263  2021-10-29 15:35   test/Text Document.odt
       28  2021-10-29 15:37   test/desc.txt
---------                     -------
    23977                     8 files
```

in a bashscript

```
mkdir -p test
echo -n "Enter contents of desc file: " 
read content && echo "$content" > test/description.txt
zip -ur existing.zip test
```

Comment: Madhubala, Sorry for the last part of my original message, I wasn't meaning it to sound like a demand, I was just tired before writing the message and really needed some help with it. Regarding

Comment: your bash script post, the zipping part of it works great, but for the description, I wanted to use the filename without the extension for the actual description, how could I go about using the filename (without extension) for the description?

Comment: @Brian it's not clear how are you getting the description file name at first place ; please edit your question and add more deatils/a sample of filenames as an example ; As per the SE rules one question at a time so ask a new question; also accept the answer if it helped